# What is the meaning of Slave Offset and how is this term defined in plc programming context?

Tags: offset, plc, master-slave, siemens

Currently I am working on IEC-104 Protocol with Siemens S7-1500 and I came across a term which is Slave Offset. What is the meaning of slave offset and how is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

Slave offset is a term used in synchronization between two rotary and linear axes.  the axes are the representation of the positioning of the virtual or real motors.  usually each motor is assigned an axis which it will follow directly or according to different criteria.  To manage the synchronous movement of two or more axes, technological blocks are used (e.g. mc_camin). These technologies not only allow you to assign synchronous movements between the axes but also allow you to establish at what fixed distance they must follow the master axis.  example: the master is a rotary axis and the slave motor synchronized with an offset of 10 degrees, it means that when the master axis is in the 0 degrees position the slave axis will be at 10 degrees.  the same applies to linear axes where the offset is on one unit of distance measurement.

Here a documentation of the siemens block [McCamIn siemens](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/886/109758886/att_956353/v1/109758886_FAQ_McCamIn_DirectSynchronousSetting_en.pdf)